# how to run a line of code after a delay in a paralel thread node js?

Tags: node.js, multithreading, delay, scheduling

I need to schedule one of the tasks in a web site while being able to use the rest of the website features

I'm reading about async and sync execution but not sure if there is a simpler way to do it.

This task is sending something to the Windows cmd to run a program, so I thought about two options:

1. Adding a command in the cmd sentence to delay the execution of the line
2. Defining this line of code as a thread which includes a "wait" action with the specificed delay

I'm trying this code:

var schedule = require('node-schedule');

```
                            schedule.scheduleJob('6 * * * *', function(){
                            //console.log('The answer to life, the universe, and everything!');
                            command += "--test project://" + projectName + "/" + tc.name + " ";
                           });
```

This runs the command in minute 6.

I'm a bit newbie in the language, so I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it.
What do you guys think? Any node js function I could use?

Comment: What are you _actually_ trying to do, though? Because the normal approach would be to define both jobs in your package.json (e.g. running a server and "some other thing") and then running those two tasks in parallel (by using `npm-run-all`, for example).

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I have a website that runs an application through bash commands on Windows when you click the button "Run". Now I want to have a button named "schedule" which postpones the execution of the application to a selected date/time.

Comment: So just create [a normal scheduled task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/scheduledtasks/?view=winserver2012r2-ps)? Also note that you're talking about windows, but you're saying "bash commands" so either you're using bash (in which case, just create a crontab job?), or you're _not_ using bash, in which case you shouldn't be using the name for a very specific shell language.